# Communications between multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, messaging

I have specific number of threads, say 5 threads: A, B, C, D, and E.

I'd love to know what are some specific approaches to design a communication interface between these threads such that the receiver thread can distinguish messages from different senders.
Also, each thread should also be able to send message to itself.

For example, can I design each thread to have multiple `BlockingQueues`, one for each sender thread? Also, each thread has a list of receivers where it can send message to? Is it recommended?

What is the best/reasonable way to implement this in java?

Comment: Create a message queue for each pair of threads that need to communicate? (Actually one for each direction)

Comment: The issue of threading is an implementation choice and not particularly relevant to your question, which is about restricting instances to "communicate" with a limited number of other instances.

Comment: The answer will depend on *how* you need this communication to be, i.e. does B need to wait until A sends a message? What about A waiting for B? And same for others...

Comment: Doesn't this also depend on how the program is structured? Are all 5 threads in the same object, or do they each go with a different object?

Comment: Make sure to read Bohemian's comment closely. Your question has nothing to do with threads. That the different bits of code that need to communicate happen to be running in distinct threads has no effect on how you design the communication.

Comment: You're right. I'll need to reword it. But my main question is how to design a communication interface between threads. I'd love to hear different ideas/approaches.

Comment: @abcXYZ It's not a "communication interface between threads". It's how one piece of code tells another piece of code something, typically what work to do. That the code happens to run in different threads is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

You want a Message Passing Interface between each thread. I would structure the program by creating the message passing interfaces first, then constructing thread A's class and thread B's class and passing the interface as an argument to both. Then start the threads.

For java, the [TransferQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TransferQueue.html) class looks like a good choice. If you don't need some of its features you can also just use the [ConcurrentLinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html). Use two for bi-directional communication.